Migrating My Site content database from Sharepoint Server 2019 to Sharepoint Subscription Edition
I am upgrading the content databases from My Site hosted on Sharepoint 2019 farm to Sharepoint subscription edition. When I run Test-SPContentDatabase, I get the following error message:
Database WSS_Content_MySite has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364] but isn't installed on current farm.
I check thed that this is related to Access Services. How can I add the feature to the web application so that is mounted successfully in the new farm.

Access Services 2010 and Access Services 2013 have been removed from SharePoint Subscription Edition. That's why the feature d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364 is not installed on the current farm, and cannot be installed.
Is Access Services used on your current SharePoint 2019? Maybe the service was provisionned but never used?

If yes, this is a major issue for your migration project.
If not, you should clean up the SharePoint 2019 by removing this service before starting a migration.

Source: What's deprecated or removed from SharePoint Server Subscription Edition
